# Word document lost without a trace

Tags: macos, file-management, microsoft-word-2011

My friend experienced something I can't understand. She had a document saved locally on a Macbook Air using Office 2011, went in today and found it gone. The only sign it once existed was in Word's Recent Document area:

[image: fail]

I looked in the containing folder using finder, did an `ls -la` and saw no hidden backup files. I then went as far as running `find / -name "Policy Paper.docx"` without hitting anything. Recent documents show nothing more than this gap.

What in the world is there left to do?

Comment: I guess you could use a file recovery program to check for deleted files. But this is the reason you should keep regular backups of any file you care about.

Comment: You might also do a search on the hard drive for the file name - could have been accidentally moved via Finder.

Comment: Great call ernie - that's what the `find` command does. Very much agreed David. Past that option at this time, so still interested in solving this particular issue as well.

Comment: Might be worth doing  find / -name "STARolicySTAR"  which would find similarly named files, e.g. if the extension has been changed somehow. Change STAR to an asterix character in that - I can't seem to make it show up here!

Comment: [This link](http://www.squidoo.com/recovertrashmac) might help.

Comment: I think the Trash is located locally under the username, and is skipped by find (just tested).  Did you already check `~/.Trash`?

Comment: How about searching for any docx files modified in the appropriate timeframe? I see folks accidentally rename files by clicking on the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Mac Word recovery software - "uFlysoft Data recovery for Mac", that is available on internet and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Time Machine and restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

As many mentioned, I can of course try to go recover from backup. No one addressed what the dotted box in Word showing a document that no longer exists means. There is no answer out there at this time - closing this one.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to a user of mine, and I was able to restore the file using Time Machine.